# Display ContextAttribs and GL11 Projection Matrix Mode - Function is not supported

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am getting an error when I try to set the Matrix mode of my LWJGL program to GL_Projection.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
```

The error is :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
>           at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
>           at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.java:2075)
>           ....

I have tracked down the error to when I make my Display. When I remove my ContexAttribs my code doesn't display the error and renders! ( when I comment out the code that needs the contexattribs )

This is my code:

display code:

```
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withProfileCore(true).withForwardCompatible(true);
Display.create(new PixelFormat().withDepthBits(24).withSamples(4), attribs);
Display.setTitle(TITLE);
Display.setInitialBackground(1, 1, 1);
GL11.glEnable(GL13.GL_MULTISAMPLE);
GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

initialization method:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);

textureID = loadTexture("res/hud.png");

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

rendering method:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

{
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(width, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(width, height);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, height);
}

glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Does anyone know how I could get this code working with the contextAttribs?

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: I have all the functions and variables in GL11 statically imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, drawing with `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences is deprecated since more than 10 years. See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) for a state of the art way of rendering.

With the line

```
ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withProfileCore(true).withForwardCompatible(true);
```

a [OpenGL **core** profile Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#OpenGL_3.2_and_Profiles) with [Forward compatibility](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Forward_compatibility) bit set is generated.

In this context all the deprecated functions like `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences, matrix stack (`glMatrixMode`), the standard light model etc. are removed. This causes the error.

See also [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context)

Skip the setting of the forward compatibility bit (`.withForwardCompatible(true)`) to solve the issue.